# AND operator + addition faster than a subtraction

Tags: c++, assembly, execution-time

I've measured the execution time of following codes:

```
volatile int r = 768;
r -= 511;

volatile int r = 768;
r = (r & ~512) + 1;
```

assembly:

```
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
sub     eax, 511
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax

mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
and     ah, 253
add     eax, 1
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
```

the results:

```
Subtraction time: 141ns   
AND + addition: 53ns
```

I've run the snippet multiple times with consistent results.
Can someone explain me why is this the case even tho there is one more line of assembly for AND + addition version?

Comment: Because subtraction is more expensive than addition ^^

Comment: @invisal okay, but why?

Comment: Measurement error. I guess the different code length affected alignment in other parts of the code (you have used a loop, right?)

Comment: Because subtraction is more complicated. You can check http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_7.html and http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/binary-subtractor.html

Comment: And how did you time these? Chances are you're timing them incorrectly.

Comment: @invisal doesn't matter. They go through the same ALU anyway, not one through an adder that is somehow a "partial cycle" faster than the subtractor. That's not really workable.

Comment: @invisal There is nothing there that says it is more complicated or takes longer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assertion that one snippet is faster than the other is mistaken.
If you look at the code:

```
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
....
mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
```

You'll see that the running time is dominated by the load/store to memory.
Even on Skylake this will take 2+2 = 4 cycles minimum.
The 1 cycles that the `sub` or the 3<sup>*)</sup> cycles that the `and bytereg/add full reg` takes simply disappears into memory access time.
On older processors such as Core2 it takes 5 cycles minimum to do a load/store pair to the same address.

It is difficult to time such short sequences of code and care should be taken to ensure you have the correct methodology.
You also need to remember that `rdstc` is not accurate on Intel processors and runs out of order to boot.

[If you use proper timing code like](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf):

```
.... x 100,000    //stress the cpu using integercode in a 100,000 x loop to ensure it's running at 100%
cpuid             //serialize instruction to make sure rdtscp does not run early.
rdstcp            //use the serializing version to ensure it does not run late   
push eax
push edx
mov reg1,1000*1000   //time a minimum of 1,000,000 runs to ensure accuracy
loop:
...                  //insert code to time here
sub reg1,1           //don't use dec, it causes a partial register stall on the flags.
jnz loop             //loop
//kernel mode only!
//mov eax,cr0          //reading and writing to cr0 serializes as well.
//mov cr0,eax
cpuid                //serialization in user mode.
rdstcp               //make sure to use the 'p' version of rdstc.
push eax
push edx
pop 4x               //retrieve the start and end times from the stack.
```

Run the timing code a 100x and take the **lowest** cycle count.
Now you'll have an accurate count to within 1 or 2 cycles.
You'll want to time an empty loop as well and subtract the times for that so that you can see the net time spend executing the instructions of interest.

If you do this you'll discover that `add` and `sub` run at exactly the same speed, just like it does/did in every x86/x64 CPU since the 8086.
This, of course, is also what [Agner Fog](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf), [the Intel CPU manuals](http://developer.intel.com/), [the AMD cpu manuals](http://developer.amd.com/resources/developer-guides-manuals/), and [just about](https://gmplib.org/~tege/x86-timing.pdf) [any other source](http://instlatx64.atw.hu/) available say.

*) `and ah,value` takes 1 cycle, then the CPU stalls for 1 cycle due the partial register write and the `add eax,value` takes another cycle.

**Optimized code**

```
sub     DWORD PTR [rbp-4],511
```

Might be faster if you don't need to reuse the value elsewhere, the latency is slow at 5 cycles, but the reciprocal throughput is 1 cycle, which is much better than either of your versions.

Answer (score -1):

The full machine code is

```
8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
2d ff 01 00 00          sub    eax,0x1ff
89 45 fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],eax
```

vs

```
8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
80 e4 fd                and    ah,0xfd
83 c0 01                add    eax,0x1
89 45 fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],eax
```

This means for the code for the secound operation is in fact only one byte longer (11 vs 12). Most likely the CPU fetches code in larger units them bytes, so fetching isn't much slower. Also it can decode multiple instructions at the same time, so there the first sample doesn't have an advantage either. Executing a single `add`, `and` or `sub` each takes up a single ALU pass so they all take only one clock on a single execution unit. That's a 1 ns advantage for you sub on a 1GHz CPU.

So basically both operations are more or less the same. The difference may be attributed to some other factors. Maybe memory cell `rbp-0x4` is still in L1 cache before your run the secound code sniplet. Or the instructions for the first sniplet are located worse reachable in memory. Or the CPU was able to run the secound sniplet speculativly before you started measuring etc., you would need to know how you measured the speed etc. to decide that.

Comment: The fetching is irrelevant, the CPU fetches 32 bytes at a time and it runs repeated code from the uop cache, which does not need to be fetched nor decoded.  Your assertion that `sub` vs `and bytereg+add wholereg` takes the same time is incorrect. the first takes 1 cycle, the latter 3. There is also no OoO, because all instructions are in a dependency chain.

Comment: Yes, I actually said that the CPU fetches code in larger units them bytes. I didn't say they take exactly the same time, only more or less the same, compared to the other factors. Regarding OoO, I didn't say that the instructions can be executed out of order, only that they might already be executed alongside what ever is done before this sniplet. (Well to be fair that's unlikely).
In addition, are you sure about the 3 cycles? Wouldn't the CPU just rename an other register to eax?

Comment: The CPU can't rename, because there is a dependency chain. It only renames if you're using the same register but are _not_ in dependency chain. The instructions in the middle can not be executed before (i.e. OoO) because they depend on the result of the first move. And as stated Intel does not fetch code in a loop, that code is already in the uop cache, fully fetched and decoded.  Code outside of a loop is almost never time critical. It's complicated, you can read all about it at: http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf